# Setting default encoding for non-unicode programs/documents in Mac OS X 10.5

Tags: macos, mac, fonts, encoding, unicode

I'm trying to open a document that has non-Unicode Arabic text in it using Mac OS X. I know way around this problem in Windows XP for example: the user can set the default encoding for non-Unicode programs to be any language (under Regional and Language Options --- Advanced), but I can't figure out how to do the same in OS X.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there's no global way of doing this in OSX as in Windows. It has to be done on an application by application level --- and not all applications support changing the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

what program are you using to view the text ?

Mac Os X supports non-unicode text but you'll need the proper fonts installed to view the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go to:

- System Preferences > Language & Region > Apps

and then insert the specific application you use to open that document & specify the language setting.